# Nested Table seems to be causing null childnodes error

Tags: knockout.js, nested-table

**Error Message:** Message: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null

**Template: (Part 1)**

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.Mark" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" step="1" data-bind="value: $data.Quantity" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.Description" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.Type" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" data-bind="value: $data.BaseLength" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" data-bind="value: $data.TCXLNumber" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" data-bind="value: $data.TCXLLength" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" data-bind="value: $data.TCXRNumber" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" data-bind="value: $data.TCXRLength" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" data-bind="value: $data.SeatDepthLeft" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" data-bind="value: $data.SeatDepthRight" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" data-bind="value: $data.BCXCount" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" data-bind="value: $data.Uplift" /></td>
    <td data-bind="foreach: $data.Remarks">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data" />
    </td>
    <td><button class="w100 round alert deleteEntity">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

**Template: (Part 2)**

```
<tr>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">LoadInfo</th>
                <th colspan="2">Load1</th>
                <th colspan="2">Load2</th>
                <th rowspan="2"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Distance</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Distance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'LoadInfoTableTemplate', foreach: $data.LoadInfos }">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</tr>
```

**View: (Original)**

```
<form>
    <table class="grid">
        <thead data-bind="template: { name: 'JoistsTableHeaderTemplate', with: $data[0] }"></thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'JoistsTableBodyTemplate', foreach: $data }"></tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**View: (Modified)**

```
<form>
    <table class="grid">
        <thead data-bind="template: { name: 'JoistsTableHeaderTemplate', with: $data[0] }"></thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'JoistsTableBodyTemplate', foreach: $data }"></tbody>
    </table>
    <table data-bind="foreach: $data" style="display:none;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">LoadInfo</th>
                <th colspan="2">Load1</th>
                <th colspan="2">Load2</th>
                <th rowspan="2"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Distance</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Distance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'LoadInfoTableTemplate', foreach: $data.LoadInfos }">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Explanation:**

Template-Part-1 works perfectly and loads using Knockout perfectly. Template-Part-2 if done outside of Template-Part-1 works (see *View: (Modified)*). If I append a `<tr></tr>` to Template-Part-1 and place Template-Part-2 inside of the `<tr></tr>` then the error message is given.

Simply put, I am trying to nest the table in Template-Part-2 inside a table-row that will be appended to Template-Part-1. This throws the Error Message above. If I however, place Template-Part-2 inside its own table after the table (and add appropriate data-bind attribute) I wish to nest it in, it works perfectly.

**Question:** Does anyone know why trying to nest my table (Template-Part-2) is causing the error? How do I fix it? Is there some Knockout Rule that doesn't allow something that doesn't require a bind to be templated?

Comment: Are you able to create a jsFiddle to help explain the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem will be the context.  You have $data all over your views but depending on the context, that $data will be different objects.  As you move into nested `foreach` loops the value of $data will change to the object of the current loop.  This is something that I get caught on all the time and ahve found that [Knockout Binding Context Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) is a great help.

Also you will need to add a `<td></td>` to template part 2 as it wont be valid html.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">LoadInfo</th>
                <th colspan="2">Load1</th>
                <th colspan="2">Load2</th>
                <th rowspan="2"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Distance</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Distance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'LoadInfoTableTemplate', foreach: $data.LoadInfos }">
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: *facepalm* I'm almost certain it's cause of the missing `<td></td>` I can't believe I overlooked that. I know for certain my context is correct because that's the first thing I checked when I was having problems. Checked it like 10 times. I'm not at work atm so I can't say 100% but I'm almost certain that is the problem. Thank you.

Comment: It definitely was the problem, still can't believe I overlooked that :/ Thank you.